# Capybara not finding elements on page

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, selenium, capybara

I have a landing page that contains 10 links which i need to click through and load. I'm using Capybara with Selenium web driver to create a RSpec test that will load the website, login, go to landing page, click the first dashboard link in landing page, return to landing page, click second link, etc.

Whenever Capybara returns to the landing page it always returns ElementErrorNotFound when attempting to click the 2nd link. My guess is that the JavaScript isn't loading before the element is clicked, but isn't Capybara now smart enough to wait for the page to load?

Comment: Can you provide the code and html? How do we know what is the wrong without any info?

Answer (score 0):

I am not to familiar with Ruby and Capybara but Selenium has Implicit Waits which should take care of that issue.  http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

You could always loop until it returns the element you are looking for, also.